# Does the Xamarin Forms InAppBillingPlugin have a bug in the connection code? Is there a workaround?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've copied the following code almost verbatim from James Montemagno's **InAppBillingPlugin**:

https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/CheckAndRestorePurchases.html

The version I am using is **6.6.1** for Xamarin Forms Android.

```
public async Task<bool> WasItemPurchased(string productId)
{
    //various declarations
    //...
    //
    IInAppBilling billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
    IEnumerable<InAppBillingPurchase> purchases;
    InAppBillingPurchase purchase = null;
    bool success = false;
    bool connected;


    try
    {
        connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();
        if (!connected)
        {
            ShowToast("not connected");
            return false;
        }

        //debug
        ShowToast("connected");

        //check purchases
        purchases = await billing.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);

        //no purchases found
        if (purchases == null)
            return false;

        purchase = purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Id, productId, true) == 0);

        //specific purchase not found
        if (purchase == null)
            return false;

        //handle purchase
        //...
        //

        success = true;
    }
    catch (InAppBillingPurchaseException e)
    {
        //handle exceptions
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Something has gone wrong
        msg = "Payment module error";
    }
    finally
    {
        await billing?.DisconnectAsync();
    }

    return success;
}
```

To test the code for offline behaviour, I turn off the data and wifi on my phone and run the method through the debugger.

The following line:

```
var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();
```

...is returning `connected == true`

Has anyone else experienced this? If there is a bug here, I'm not sure I can effectively use this plugin, or use it in a manner where I can trust the results.

Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Comment: To my experience with the plugin, it works fine for online scenarios. When offline, attempting to get the available products may lead to errors, but please mind that the stores do keep some cached data. That might be the reason why connecting still works when offline. The plugin only acts like a proxy with a common interface. If you want to disable purchases when offline, you could check if the device is connected to the internet using Xamarin Essentials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify, when you say "stores do keep some cached data", do you mean the data is cached on the mobile device itself and that, when offline, the plugin may be accessing this local data set, rather then doing a call to the Google servers?

Comment: Indeed. Purchases are cached, IDs may be cached, too. Each platform handles this differently, though. Related, but not identical to this: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/90

Comment: Just read the link from J.M. you sent me. With regards to his comment on using keystores, what's your take on that? Is he saying it is probably more safe to store the purchase transaction info manually in secure storage than simply rely on the plugin reading the cache? Would `Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage` be adequate for such a task? Sorry if this is drifting slightly off from the original question, but I'm still trying to work out the best practices for this whole process.

Comment: That's a tricky question. SecureStorage would mean saving the transaction exclusively on the current device and then you wouldn't have access to it when the user switches devices unless you offer a "restore purchase" feature. It all depends on your use cases. Do you want to unlock specific functionality? Do you use a backend? It takes some planning.

Comment: I'm selling a non-consumable feature, and don't want the overhead of a backend server at this point in time. I'm thinking that keeping it exclusively on the current device will be ok for my purposes, because I plan to re-check from time to time anyway with the app store that the purchase is indeed genuine (hence the code above). This is to circumvent any possible hacking of the app to 'impersonate' a purchaser, for want of a better word. Does that strategy make sense?

Comment: Yes, in short, you can do that.